# Geting null instead of string from the object property

Tags: ios

Please take a look at this [image: fragment of debugger]
So... I got this property filled, right? It belongs to my `visit` object

So I trye to get that string from it using:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"Doctor: ", visit.doctorName]);
```

Here is the output:

> Doctor: /(null)

What is going on here?

Comment: Not even sure what the frame do, but surely has nothing to do with my cell beeing invisible

Comment: May you show us how you declare the property doctorName? Do you use ARC?

Comment: he changed the question and so obsoleted the detailed answer below

Comment: Problem was that I have't synthesised properties and I'm using 4.3 SDK . You pointed me to the right direction @LucaBartoletti. You might wanna post it as an answer so I could reward you with extra points :) Please leve your answer below intact, because I'm planning to use it in the future

Comment: Glad to help you. I update the answer. I'll find the old one in the revision history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to the updated Question:**

May you show us how you declare the property doctorName? Do you use ARC?

Comment: ok overrided layoutSubviews method, but what should I implement there? Coould you provide me example of creating a subview of contentView with height set? I would really appreciate it

Comment: also edited the question and added a clue, please check it out

Comment: That's a great project "picture"! Yeah, I just noticed that's a leftover from feature that was sliding in and out delete buttons which were on the Yelow background of your project. I don't need that anymore. So, frame is not important here at all. The problem is after I set text to the UILabel my label dissapears.

Comment: the problem seems to be completly different, had to change the question